# How can I add sentences format (commas, period and plus sign)

Tags: grammar

Greetings
I would like to add sentence format comma, period and plus sign in the following latex code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{48, 122, 219}
\newcommand{\isnoun}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{{\color{color1}\mathbf{N}}}{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\isverb}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{V}}{{\color{color2}\text{#1}}}}}
% new command comma, plus sign and period
\newcommand{\iscomma}[1].......
\newcommand{\isplusign}[1]..............
\newcommand{\isperiod}[1]................
\begin{document}
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country. 

\end{document}
```

Thank again for your help.

Comment: It would be helpful if you described what kind of output you are expecting...

Comment: camp, thank you very much. I would like to write these to the top of sentence words. Japan is a country, = N + V + Comma or period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, something like this where the annotated version picks up even non standard settings of the second example.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{219, 48, 122}
\definecolor{color2}{RGB}{48, 122, 219}
\definecolor{color3}{RGB}{200,0,0}
\newcommand{\isnoun}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize\color{color1}\textbf{N}}}{\strut\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\isverb}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize\color{color2}\textbf{V}}}{\strut\text{#1}}}}
% new command comma, plus sign and period
\newcommand{\iscomma}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\makebox[0pt]{\scriptsize\color{color3}\textbf{P}}}{\strut\text{#1}}}\spacefactor\sfcode`#1 }
\let\isplusign\iscomma
\let\isperiod\iscomma

\begin{document}


Japan is a country, France is a country.
Japan is a country, France is a country.
Japan is a country, France is a country.
Japan is a country, France is a country.


\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 


\bigskip
% big sentence space
\spaceskip=1em plus .5em minus .2em 
\xspaceskip=2em  plus 1em minus .1em

Japan is a country, France is a country.
Japan is a country, France is a country.
Japan is a country, France is a country.
Japan is a country, France is a country.

\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 
\isnoun{Japan} \isverb{is} a country\iscomma{,} \isnoun{France} \isverb{is} a country\isperiod{.} 

\end{document}
```

Comment: David, thank you very much. However, I would commas, plus sign and period to be in the same line with N, V on top of line of sentence. 1:  N + V .  2. N + V + N, N +V.

Comment: ```% Adding commas, plus sign, period.
\newcommand{\iscomma}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{,}}{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\isplussign}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{+}}{\text{#1}}}}
\newcommand{\isperiod}[1]{\ensuremath{\overset{\mathbf{.}}{\text{#1}}}} ```

Comment: I have tried the above code, but the code does not work. commas, period and plus sign are in the same line as sentence words

Comment: @user3056542 you have not used the definition I gave in the answer, with `\strut`

Comment: David, thank you again. Is it possible to use dot instead of P? and the same for comma and plus sign symbols?

Comment: @user3056542 did you try it ? of course yes the `P` is just arbitrary text you can use `.` or whatever you want.

Comment: Yes, I have tried the code you gave in the answer. In short I am learning english grammar. so I would like to see that I can label on top of each sentences. where should I put the command \strut?

Comment: @user3056542 if you use the command in my answer it has `\strut` in the right place.

Comment: David, thank you very much. it works.